# What is the etymology of "market capitalisation"

Tags: etymology

I want to ask a question about the term 'market capitalisation'.

In finance, this term is used to often refer to the total "value" of a company, expressed by multiplying the number of shares by the price of just one share.

I have trouble however understanding the etymology of the phrase.

I understand that capitalisation comes from the word 'capital', which has roots in Latin as the *head* of a specific entity. In accounting, the *head* (or the *main* part of a company, in much the same way that the human *head* is the most important part of the body) is the amount of money that the company has to spend on its functions and keep it afloat.

However, I can't link the use of 'capitalisation' to the context given above with the total value of a company expressed in terms of its share price. **How does capitalisation link to the term 'market capitalisation' in a logical fashion?**

*There is no etymology or history of how the term has been used as far as I have looked on the internet, so I would like to ask here as I'm quite confused by it all.*

Comment: [**Capitalisation**](https://www.transactioncapital.co.za/downloads/20210930_Transaction%20Capitals_RA_FINAL.pdf) - *The provision of capital for a company, or the conversion of income or assets into capital.* The main reason for qualifying it as ***market** capitalisation* is probably to spell out the fact that we're talking about something relating to *financial **markets*** (nothing to do with orthography, and the use of capital letters). But more generally, the basic "etymology" is the same for all modern senses of ***capital*** and derived / inflected forms thereof.

Comment: ...but I don't think it's helpful to interpret ***capital*** in its accounting sense as a reference to "the head or the main part of a company". The allusion to "head" is *way* too far back in history be particularly relevant there.